# How to use a jQuery plugin in an Angular 2 component?

Tags: jquery, angular

I would like to use a background image slider plugin called Vegas on only the home page in my Angular 2 app. The jQuery plugin has been installed under the /node_module directory via npm.

Here is my home page component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'vegas';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, router:Router, title:Title) {
        router.events.subscribe((url)=>{
            title.setTitle('Home Page');
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        $('body').vegas({
            slides: [
                { src: "../../img/home/1.jpg" },
                { src: "../../img/home/2.jpg" },
                { src: "../../img/home/3.jpg" },
                { src: "../../img/home/4.jpg" }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

I've got this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by:
>   __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_jquery___default(...)(...).vegas is not a function...

It seems the plugin files were not loaded. How do I properly load and use a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Where are you importing `vegas` from? Do you not have to specify?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I'm new to Angular 2. Doesn't it load everything up when I `import 'vegas';` after the npm installation? Or should I import the whole path of the javascript file? like this: `import '../../node_modules/vegas/dist/vegas.js';` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular but the norm is to tell the module where to import from - the path

Answer (score 0):

You should give path like this.

```
Import 'vegas' from 'vegas/dist/vegas';
```